# Lifting x86 machine code to LLVM IR

Tags: assembly, llvm

I would like to translate a simple x86_64 machine code into LLVM IR, which can be later analyzed. For my particular use case, I need to be able to work with just instructions and opcodes directly, and I don't have access to the binary itself.

To my current understanding, I should be able to convert x86 instructions using tools such as `rellume` and `remill`. With their help, I am able to create LLVM IR code, however, I am not entirely sure whether the results I am getting are correct.

First I need to create machine code for a very simple application (this is just for testing purposes):

- Compile the source code [1]

  - `gcc simple.c -o simple.o`
- Dissemble using `objdump` [2]

  - `objdump -d simple.o`
  - At this point, I get separate functions `add` and `main`

Then, I provide a function that I want to translate into LLVM IR to `remill` as bytes:

- Translate `add` function into LLVM using `remill`

  - `bytes` = `add` function as bytes
  - the result should be a LLVM IR of the `add` function

```
docker run --rm \
 -it remill \
 --arch amd64 \
 --ir_out /dev/stdout \
 --bytes f30f1efa554889e54883ec10be03000000bf01000000e8cdffffff8945fc8b45fcc9c3
```

My questions:

- Is my current workflow to translate x86 instructions into LLVM IR correct? Am I missing something? (I am aware of tools such as `McSema`, however, for my use case I need to be able to transform opcodes).
- How can I verify the produced LLVM IR?

  - After producing LLVM IR of an even simpler example [3], I tried to run it with `lli` unsuccessfully.

---

1. Source code

```
int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int c = add(1, 3);
    return c;
}
```

2. Dump of `objdump`

```
...

0000000000001129 <add>:
    1129:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    112d:   55                      push   %rbp
    112e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1131:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
    1134:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
    1137:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
    113a:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
    113d:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
    113f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    1140:   c3                      ret    

0000000000001141 <main>:
    1141:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1145:   55                      push   %rbp
    1146:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1149:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
    114d:   be 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%esi
    1152:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
    1157:   e8 cd ff ff ff          call   1129 <add>
    115c:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
    115f:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
    1162:   c9                      leave  
    1163:   c3                      ret    

...
```

3. 

```
int main
{
  int val = 2
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [RetDec](https://github.com/avast/retdec)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190471/how-can-i-lifting-x86-64-assembly-code-to-llvm-ir